# Is the following set uncountable or countable?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $X$ be the set of real numbers except the integers which are multiple of $2$

Then I need to tell whether the set is uncountable or countable .

Now ,Here is my reasoning:

Suppose $Y$ be the integers which are multiple of $2$, clearly this set is countable(there exist a one one onto map to set $\mathbb{N}$).

so $X \cup Y =\mathbb{R}$

Suppose that if $X$ were to be countable then $X \cup Y$ will be a countable set,thus $\mathbb{R}$ will be countable which is a contradiction

So, $X$ must be a uncountable set.

Is my answer and reasoning correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean $\Bbb R \setminus 2\Bbb Z$ ?

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct. Shortly: the union of two countable sets is countable, but $\mathbb R$ is not.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Question seems pointless, since set of all irrationals is already uncountable.

Comment: every integer is a multiple of $2$. Probably the correct term meant is "integer multiple of $2$", that is numbers or the form $r\cdot2$ where $r$ is in integer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct.  Removing a countable set from an uncountable set leaves an uncountable set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! It is correct!  But also note that, for example,  $$(0,1) \subset \Bbb R \setminus 2 \Bbb Z$$ and $(0,1)$ is uncountable, so the set $\Bbb R \setminus 2 \Bbb Z$ is uncountable too!